# mysql update query in python

Tags: python, mysql

i have a table deviceInfo with 4 columns(id,brand_name,model_name,marketing_name)
and want to update this table. The xml sheet may have values for this columns or may not,so to update these columns i want an update query but is stuck up with what will be the where clause since the id is auto incremented.

```
sqlquery = 'update deviceInformation set brand_name=%s, model_name=%s, marketing_name=%s where ???????? ;'
cursor.execute(sqlquery,brand_name, model_name, marketing_name)
```

Comment: If the id is in the spreadsheet, then why don't you use it in the where criteria?

Comment: the id is not in the xml sheet but in the table which is auto incremented

Comment: Then how do you know which record the data in the xml document relates to?